# phalcon include modules in rest

Tags: rest, module, structure, phalcon

I am trying to include a module in Phalcon Micro Application. Is that possible?

I have a structure like this

```
common/
    components/
      ...
    modules/
       system
          components
             ...
          controllers
             ...
       rest
          components
             ...
          controllers
             ...
       www
          controllers
             ...
www/
   index.php -> Loads /Phalcon/Mvc/Application($di);

api/
   index.php -> Loads /Phalcon/Mvc/Micro($di);
```

The `www` registers the modules from config

I want the `api` to register the rest module from config and include the controllers and the components of that module. Is that possible?

Thanks,
Gasim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously all is possible !

If you want to keep your structure with application+micro I think the best way is to create 3 configs.

- A first config that is common with both of api and www
- A second one which is loaded only by your www with its one router
- A thirds one which is loaded only by your api with its one microrouter and which redefines the different paths to the rest module.

---

If you want just to use a multi module application with a single config file, then I can advice you to use  [the domain recognition](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#hostname-constraints) in your router thanks to [the `setHostName()` method](http://api.phalconphp.com/en/1.2.3/Phalcon/Mvc/Router/Route#setHostname-details).

Then in your config file you define an api hostname and a www hostname that you use everytime. You may also put them in global constant for more convenience.

```
// an api get route
$router->add("/getsomething",...)
    ->via("GET")
    ->setHostname(MyApp::HOSTNAME_API);

// an api post route
$router->add("/postsomething",...)
    ->via("POST")
    ->setHostname(MyApp::HOSTNAME_API);

// a www route
$router->add("/",...)->setHostname(MyApp::HOSTNAME_WEB);
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to include a module in Phalcon Micro Application. Is that possible?

Yes, no problem!

> I want the api to register the rest module from config and include the controllers and the components of that module. Is that possible?

Looking at your description and structure I understand it as you would like to separate the configuration of the www module and api module. This will work fine and you only need to include your api configuration in www/index.php (since that is where you start your application and where all your requests will go). Good luck!